# How can I jump farther in Ski Safari?

Tags: ski-safari

I've noticed that sometimes after I jump of a ramp or leap from the top of a steep hill I'll catch a bit of air and float a bit rather than dropping like a rock towards the hill below me. Is there something I'm doing that is helping me make a longer jump or is it random? Can I do something similar with penguin skis, yetis and snowmobiles?

Comment: You mean other than tapping the screen to jump? The only time I ever drop like a rock off of a ramp is if I don't tap the screen. The game doesn't seem to care if you do a quick-tap or long-tap to jump higher from what I can tell.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I clarified a bit; I mean as I'm going off a steep hill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that having the correct inclination when you fall can help you achieve speed. you see that you have the correct inclination when you see air around the guy with the skis.